# Volume mounting with docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

Following is my docker-stack file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-app:    
    image: my-image:latest    
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/certs   
    ports:
      - 6401:6401
    networks:
      my-net:        
         ipv4_address: 192.168.0.4
networks:
  my-net:
    external: true
```

It works fine on my machine, binding certs folder to certs inside the container. However doesn't work in my CI pipeline where i am deploying this service inside a docker-stack-node image. The error i get is

> invalid mount config for type "bind": bind mount source path does not
>   exist.

I read that If you bind mount a host path into your service’s containers, the path must exist on every swarm node. So, I think i need to create a named volume. However, with the named volume i can't specify source path of certs. It's confusing. Can someone help with this?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with a named volume. I think this specifically just has to do with the CI host machine not having a certs directory where ever its running from. I'm not sure why certs are supposed to be on a mounted volume. How are the certs generated? Are they generated every single time CI runs or is it more like a secret or an artifact stored somewhere? If they're generated, you can add another image + container that generates or you can add it in from grabbing from a secrets management platform or artifact.

Comment: It's an artifact stored in repository(not a good practice but these are just for testing). So when CI runs the repo is cloned on the runner and then the service is deployed on the runner machine. When i run ls in the gitlab ci file, i can see the directory named certs there. May be the docker execution directory is different? my is using another container to copy those files?

Comment: @Niraj how did you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

To bind to a directory the directory has to exist on the host machine so `./certs` doesn't exist on the host running the container so...

If you want to bind the volume you will need to run:

`mkdir -p ./certs`

on the machine running the container and it will work.

It works on your machine because the directory exists locally.

**Copy directory to host**

```
scp -r /local/directory/ username@to_host:/remote/directory/
```

Comment: But how do i copy contents of certs to this new dir? It seems it's not there on the host directory.

Comment: Can anyone answer Niraj follow up question?

Comment: ssh or scp to the host

Answer (score 2):

@Niraj I have ran into this issue as well and have figured out that each node needs the files to run. In your case I would do this:

1. In your **Dockerfile** create the certs folder

   - `RUN mkdir /certs`
2. Change **compose-file** to use absolute path

   - `- $PWD/certs:/certs`
3. Copy certs into container

   - `docker cp <file_name> <container_id>:/certs`

Hope this helps!